# how to format axis in matplotlib.pyplot and include legend?

Tags: python, matplotlib

Got this function for the graph, want to format axis so that the graph starts from (0,0), also how do I write legends so I can label which line belongs to y1 and which to y2 and label axis.

```
  import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
  def graph_cust(cust_type): 
  """function produces a graph of day agaist customer number for a given customer type""" 
  s = show_all_states_list(cust_type)
  x = list(i['day']for i in s)
  y1 = list(i['custtypeA_nondp'] for i in s) 
  y2 = list(i['custtypeA_dp']for i in s) 
  plt.scatter(x,y1,color= 'k') 
  plt.scatter(x,y2,color='g') 
  plt.show()
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the limits on either axis using `plt.xlim(x_low, x_high)`. If you do not want to manually set the upper limit (e.g your happy with the current upper limit) then try:

```
ax = plt.subplot(111) # Create axis instance
ax.scatter(x, y1, color='k') # Same as you have above but use ax instead of plt
ax.set_xlim(0.0, ax.get_xlim()[1])
```

Note the slight difference here, we use an axis instance. This gives us the ability to return the current xlimits using `ax.get_xlim()` this returns a tuple `(x_low, x_high)` which we pick the second using `[1]`.

A minimal example of a legend:

plt.plot(x, y, label="some text")
   plt.legend()

For more on legends see [any of these examples](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/legend_auto.html)

Comment: `plt.xlabel("")` or `ax.set_xlabel("")` for a specific axis instance called `ax`.

Comment: You don't have to include `ax.get_xlim()[1]` as second argument to the `set_xlim()` method. To change only the left limit, you can either include the kwarg `left`, or just give the method one (positional) argument, i.e. `ax.set_xlim(0.0)`. See the [documentation](http://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_xlim).